# Stream stdout to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, boto

I have a stream (suppose it's stdout from a generating process) which I would like to send to s3 using boto.

Could I have a code example, please?

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is that you cannot easily stream data into s3 unless you know the size of the data you are streaming because s3 requires the size of the object to be known beforehand. You can definitely stream data out of s3 but to get data in, you'll need to buffer in memory or disk unless you are lucky enough to know the size.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much from the tutorial: 
http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/s3_tut.html#storing-data

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.key import Key
import subprocess

conn = S3Connection()
buckets = conn.get_all_buckets()
bucket = buckets[0]   # assuming you have one bucket created

output = subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'test'
k.set_contents_from_string(output)  # should be saved on S3

k.get_contents_as_string()          # should retrieve the string
```

Comment: what if the output was too big to fit into memory?

Comment: Ya, you're right, there isn't a good way to "stream" the data into a single S3 key.  The best you could do is chunk the data into one bucket using/creating multiple keys and then read out the chunks in the order they went in.